# Navigation items are not in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have designed a navigation bar using a list, but cannot get the list elements to display in the same line. I have tried `float` and `display: inline-block`, but was unsuccessful.

Can someone please assist me with vertically aligning this navigation bar so the items are all inline?

```css
html,body,ul,li,p{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}



.container{
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    
}

.body-container{
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image:url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/fugnr3fgkh5zcoa/main_image.png?dl=0);
   
}

.nav-container{
    width:1250px;
    margin:0px auto;
}


#logo {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:250px;
  }



.nav-container ul{
    list-style-type: none;
   
}

.nav-container li{
    float: left;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
}

.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child):hover {
    text-align:center;
  }

.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-top:54px;
    margin-right:50px;
  }

.social-icons{
    float:right;
    border-style: none;
}

.nav-container p{
    clear:both;
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:48px;
    color:white;
    padding-top:130px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.border{
    text-align:center;
}

.border img{
    width:230px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:42px;
}

.button-group{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:142px;
}

.nav-container .button-1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 14px;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 120%;
    background-color: rgba(41,44,47);
    opacity:0.7;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}


.nav-container .button-2 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 14px;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 120%;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:0.7;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yeseva+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/erszpjwuvy0kcpi/logo.png?dl=0" alt="Skype Logo" width="158px" height="110px"></a></li>   
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Ingredients</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Revews</li>
        <li>Reservations</li>
        <li>
                <ul>
                        
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>

        
        

        
        <p>the right ingredients <br>for the right food</p>
        <div class="border"><img src="border-1.png"></div>
        
        <div class="button-group">
        <button class="button-1">Book a table</button>
        <button class="button-2">See the Menu</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        
        
        
       
        </div>
    



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want them all item's to be vertically aligned including the logo?

Answer (score 0):

They are not in same line because you added:

```
.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-top: 54px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

As icon are in additional `ul` tag, it affect also second and third `li` in this `ul`, so there is visible difference.

I think you should put icons in first ul, like this:

```css
html,body,ul,li,p{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}



.container{
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    
}

.body-container{
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image:url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/fugnr3fgkh5zcoa/main_image.png?dl=0);
   
}

.nav-container{
    width:1250px;
    margin:0px auto;
}


#logo {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:250px;
  }



.nav-container ul{
    list-style-type: none;
   
}

.nav-container li{
    float: left;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
}

.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child):hover {
    text-align:center;
  }

.nav-container ul li:not(:first-child) {
    padding-top:54px;
    margin-right:50px;
  }

.social-icons{
    float:right;
    border-style: none;
}

.nav-container p{
    clear:both;
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:48px;
    color:white;
    padding-top:130px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.border{
    text-align:center;
}

.border img{
    width:230px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:42px;
}

.button-group{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:142px;
}

.nav-container .button-1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 14px;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 120%;
    background-color: rgba(41,44,47);
    opacity:0.7;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}


.nav-container .button-2 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 14px;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 120%;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity:0.7;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 transition: background-color 300ms ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yeseva+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/erszpjwuvy0kcpi/logo.png?dl=0" alt="Skype Logo" width="158px" height="110px"></a></li>   
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Ingredients</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Revews</li>
        <li>Reservations</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
        </ul>

        
        

        
        <p>the right ingredients <br>for the right food</p>
        <div class="border"><img src="border-1.png"></div>
        
        <div class="button-group">
        <button class="button-1">Book a table</button>
        <button class="button-2">See the Menu</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        
        
        
       
        </div>
    



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yeseva+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/erszpjwuvy0kcpi/logo.png?dl=0" alt="Skype Logo" width="158px" height="110px"></a></li>   
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Ingredients</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Revews</li>
        <li>Reservations</li>
        <li>


                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>






        <p>the right ingredients <br>for the right food</p>
        <div class="border"><img src="border-1.png"></div>

        <div class="button-group">
        <button class="button-1">Book a table</button>
        <button class="button-2">See the Menu</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>





        </div>




</body>

</html>
```

This one works as u might want to. U just should make everything in one  tag and not in 2n1.